# kodi launch with addon with java

Tags: android, kodi

I use this code to launch **kodi** from my android app.

```
startActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.xbmc.kodi"));
```

I am wondering how to launch **kodi** that auto starts playing an add on channel.